# "Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing a self made class

Tags: javascript, import, export

I looked at several other questions and tried a lot around but i cant find the problem.

Those are my imports from the HTML file:

```
<script src="./script/Graph.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="./script/Main.js"></script>
```

Graph.js:

```
export default class Graph {
  constructor() {
      this.vertices = [];
      this.edges = [];
      this.numberOfEdges = [];       
  }
  ...followed by several functions
}
```

Main.js:

```
import Graph from "./Graph.js";
```

Iam thankful for any tip :)

Comment: The script tag that uses `Main` also needs to be a module. Add `type="module"` to the script tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `import - export` in your files you need to specify the type of script file as `module`

so the corrected code would be

```html
<script src="./script/Graph.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="./script/Main.js" type="module"></script>
```

Read more on [Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)

**Extra:**

You might come across CORS (cross origin resource sharing policy) while using `import-export`, to overcome this you could use one of the following

- [Live server extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) for visual studio code
- [Node express.js](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) serve static files
- [Github pages](https://pages.github.com/) publish your project to a github repository and make use of github pages to serve your files

Comment: ok the error is gone but now Iam not able to use any function from Main.js and get the error "... not defined"

Comment: did you copy paste `...followed by several functions` this line? (its not a valid javascript syntax..)

Comment: no :D just wanted to let you know there are several functions in this class but i didnt wanted to copy them all in

Comment: huh? then how did you get this error? `"... not defined"`

Comment: I wanted to use a function i have in the Main.js file and not in the Graph.js file i just exported. This function is called buildField when i try to use it I get the error: "ReferenceError: buildField is not defined"

Comment: did you make sure you exported the function you need from main.js?

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question but export where to ? I want every function from Main.js to be executable as it is my main file

Comment: you can do `export { functionName };` from main and use `import { functionName } from './main.js';` in your subfile

Comment: what kind of subfile are you talking about? Main.js is the Main file and Graph.js is the subfile. I wanted to use the class of Graph.js in Main.js but still want the functions in Main.js to be executable without any export in the devtools.